# How can I help promote "Sports SE" as a destination for Olympics questions?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Now that the Sochi Winter Olympics are just around the corner, there will be billions of sports fans watching — and they'll have lots of questions. And since those questions will be widely searched on the Internet, Sports SE will have as good a shot at having the best answer as those, you know, competitive sites out there.

Essentially, this is a great time to recruit new members!

#### What can you do to help?

**Ask Questions**
As you watch the Olympics (and the news surrounding this event), whenever you have questions, no matter how silly, ask them here. You won't be the only one with that question. Millions of other people will, too. Ask them even if you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself… and if you do find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself.

**Have the Best Answers Anywhere**
When you're answering questions about the Olympics, do everything you can to really *overkill* it. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. Write a detailed, ultra-clear post with the best possible answer on the 'net. Help us have the best possible answer to both the common questions and the *deeper* questions about the day-to-day activities surrounding the the Olympics.

**Keep Improving the Posts**
If a question or answer comes in that is unclear, badly written, badly formatted, or in bad English, edit it into shape. We've always encouraged edits that improve spelling, grammar, and clarity. Make every question into a full sentence. Make every answer as good as it can possibly be!

#### Users will be looking for sites like this!

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to common and longer-tailed Olympic questions — questions that will be super-popular in the coming weeks as the Olympic become top headline news. And those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines. And if Sports SE continues to have great answers like we have in the past, we stand a good chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come.

Comment: [Here we go...](http://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bolympics%5D+created%3A2014-01-28..2014)

Comment: See also http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/169/what-can-we-do-to-promote-the-site-for-the-olympics

Comment: @hims056 I think this is a good sign :)