# Creating a tag for the 2014 World Cup

Tags: discussion

I was wondering should there or will there be a tag for the 2014 World Cup? I know there was an [effort](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-can-i-help-promote-sports-se-as-a-destination-for-olympics-questions) to promote the site before using the Sochi 2014 Olympics so should the same be done with the World Cup? I don't know whether the previous attempt to promote the site resulted in more new users or not but if it did then the World Cup would be another good opportunity to promote the site.

Comment: We got much bigger spikes in activity during the 2012 Euros and London Olympics than during the Sochi Olympics. However, to put that into perspective, only the single highest-activity day in all of 2012 (which occurred during the Euros) would register as more than a blip compared to our current levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's already a [world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-cup) tag for any questions for the FIFA World Cup (not to be confused with [cricket-world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cricket-world-cup)).

It's a good way to raise interest to the site, but after the event is over (examples: [london-2012](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/london-2012) [sochi-2014](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sochi-2014)), the tags are hardly ever used again (not to mention only 9 questions among the two example tags). Most of the questions are usually general Olympic questions.

I am not against promoting the site for the World Cup as we did for the Olympics. However, I'm not so sure tag creation is necessary for the World Cup given previous results for the Olympics and already having tags in place.

Comment: Ok I was wondering whether there was any benefit in creating a separate tag but that doesn't look to be the case.

Comment: May be a good idea: Create events specific tags during the event then synonimize them with the main tags at the end of the event.

Comment: @hims056 Not a bad idea, but is it necessary? Tags provide some search engine properties, so we should consider that. Here is another, somewhat related, tag proposal: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/518/should-we-add-tags-representing-years

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the tag be [fifa-world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-world-cup) or [football-world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football-world-cup)? There are other world cups, should football be the one to claim the general one?

Comment: Splitting hairs at this point. A [google search's results](https://www.google.com/search?q=world+cup&oq=world+cup&aqs=chrome..69i57.1175j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) yield the FIFA (or football) World Cup (albeit during the World Cup, but I believe this would be the case regardless). This leads me to surmise that the "World Cup" is quasi-universally in reference to the FIFA World Cup. If there are questions about other world cups, then they can be appended with the sport or league that particular world cup belongs to. Tag wiki's also go a long way.